# Embed the data itself inside foreach with Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using the knockout "foreach" as given in the following; I am basically trying to iterate a collection and print (bind) its results into my html page. The collection object "topics" is a list of  topic objects.

And "Topic" object  has the following attributes ; **link and translation.**

The link attribute itself stands for;

```
 < a href ------ />
```

The traditional binding provides a solution like this ;

```
     self.loadTemplates = function() {

        var bookTopics = "<h5 class=\"book-nav-title\" data-bind=\"text: title\"></h5>\
                         <ul id=\"navBookItems\" class=\"nav nav-stacked book-nav\">\
                            <!-- ko foreach: topics -->\
                                <li><a data-bind=\"attr: { href: link, title: translation }\"><span data-bind=\"text: translation\"></span><i class=\"pull-right\"></i></a></li>\
                            <!-- /ko -->\
                         </ul>";


        self.templateEngine.addTemplate("ui_bookTopics_tmplt", bookTopics);
    }
```

But as I specified, the link attribute is a `href` attribute by itself, that's why I would like to bind the incoming link value into the `<li>` block as it is. 
Basically I expect to put the value of link with something like `$link`. Is there any way of doing it ?

```
self.loadTemplates = function() {

        var bookTopics = "<h5 class=\"book-nav-title\" data-bind=\"text: title\"></h5>\
                         <ul id=\"navBookItems\" class=\"nav nav-stacked book-nav\">\
                            <!-- ko foreach: topics -->\
                                <li>$link<span data-bind=\"text: translation\"></span><i class=\"pull-right\"></i></a></li>\
                            <!-- /ko -->\
                         </ul>";

        self.templateEngine.addTemplate("ui_bookTopics_tmplt", bookTopics);
    }
```

Briefly,

The link has the following value ;

```
  <a href="/bookHistory.html" >History101</a>
```

the expected `<li>` to be generated ;

```
 <li><a href="/bookHistory.html"><i class="pull-right"> History101   </i></a></li>
```

Topic object sample :

```
topic = {
    link: "<a href='/bookHistory.html'>History101</a>",
    originalText: "History101",
    section: "First",
    translation: "History101"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried $data.link ?

Comment: <li>$data.link</li>  did not work out .

Comment: What about something like <li data-bind="html: $data.link" ?></li> ?

Comment: Cool but in that case I would be overwriting other variables inside <li> . In my example, there is that <span> tag being overwritten.  It there any quick way of manipulating or creating a custom <li> attribute  as I want for each iteration ?  By this way I would create my own html and apply as you suggest , perhaps ?

Comment: Can you edit your question with actual data, and the result you hope to get ?

Comment: Edited the question. Thnx in advance.

Comment: Can you add a sample of the topic object ?

Comment: Ok I also provided a sample of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use a custom binding to achieve what you want.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.linkMe = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var link = value.link.replace(value.originalText, '<i class="pull-right"></i>'+ value.translation);
        $(element).html(link)
    }
}
```

With the following html :

```
<ul id="navBookItems" class="nav nav-stacked book-nav" data-bind="foreach: topics">
    <li data-bind="linkMe: $data"></li>
</ul>
```

I've made a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/j7k5pntt/1/).

I agree the replace function is kind of hacky :S

Comment: Yep, kind of a work-around but :) nice solution. Thanks.

Comment: If you only had the href in the structure, rather than the anchor HTML, it would be more flexible and not require a hacky solution.